# Classification of states and chains in Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $S={\{1,2,3,4,5}\}$. Find out which states are: persistent, transient, null, non-null, periodic, aperiodic, ergodic and absorbing. Find closed and irreducible sets of a states. For closed sets that are irreducible find mean recurrence times and stationary distribution, when

$
P=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1/4 & 1/4 & 1/8 & 1/4 & 1/8 \\
    0 & 0 & 1/4 & 1/4 & 1/2 \\
    0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1/4 & 3/4 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
$

---

Closed sets: ${\{3,4}\}, {\{3,5}\}$

Irreducible sets: ${\{3,4}\}, {\{3,5}\}$

Sets ${\{3,4}\}, {\{3,5}\}$ consists of states: persistent and non-null

Transient set: ${\{2}\}$

I'm not sure how to find out if a state is periodic or aperiodic. If $p_{ii}>0$, then the period equals $1$, and so all the states are periodic?

Please check the above, correct me if I'm wrong anywhere, and help me with the other part of the exercise. Any will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$\{1\}$ and $\{3,4,5\}$ are closed sets, $2$ is transient and all recurrent states are aperiodic. [ $\{3,4\}$ is not a closed set because you can go from $3$ to $5$]. Of course, $1$ is an absorbing state.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my closed sets. But what about irreducible sets? I think these two are also irreducible, can I find any other ones? Can you explain me a little more why all recurrent states are aperiodic, and generally how do I find if a state is periodic or not?

Comment: From $3$ or $4$ you cannot go to $5$ so $\{3,4,5\}$ is not irreducible. Period of  state $i$ is the gcd of $\{n:p_{ii}^{(n)} >0$. If $p_{ii} >0$ the the state is aperiodoc (i.e. has period $1$) because the gcd of any set of integers containing $1$ is $1$.